# Is there a MongoDB graphical log viewer?

Tags: mongodb

MongoDB stores all logs in a text file. I am looking for a MongoDB log viewer which shows all MongoDB queries with filters in a graphical manner.

Comment: Are you looking for something to *visualize* the queries (eg. for performance/indexing analysis) or an [Admin UI](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Admin+UIs) to be able to create queries and view results?

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB Monitoring Service (MMS) is a free hosted solution to see a graphic visualisation of your database performance and other info.

Check here for more info:

https://mms.mongodb.com/

Though if you look for a "visualizer" of every single log activity, you can have a look at this project:
https://github.com/kchodorow/edda

Comment: The `edda` tool (while very cool) is actually used for visualizing events that happen in a replica set rather than at the query level.

Comment: This has long since been removed as a free service and now is integrated into Mongo's cloud hosting offering.